# Increment Values in an array (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift

So I'm in class and I'm trying to make our thing a little easier. We are trying to make a Q*bert like landscape, and we are using arrays. I'm trying to make it a lot shorter and repeatable. So I have:

```
let allCoordinate = world.allPossibleCoordinates
let coordinaterow = coordinate.row
var coordinaterow = 3

while coodinaterow != 8 {

    var heights: [Int] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

    var index = 0

    for coordinate in allCoordinates {
        if coordinate.row ==3 {
            if index == height.count {
                index = 0
            }

            for i in 0...heights[index] {
                world.place(Block(), at: coordinate)
            }
            index += 1
        }
    }

    allCoordinate += 1
    coordinaterow += 1
}
```

How would Increment the heights array like:

`0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 -- 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2 -- 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3`

and so forth

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate your collection indices reversed and check if each element is equal to zero, increase and break the iteration, otherwise just increase it:

```
var heights: [Int] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2]

for index in heights.indices.reversed() {
    if heights[index] == 0 {
        heights[index] += 1
        break
    }
    heights[index] += 1
}

print(heights)   // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Where do I insert the snippet? I put it under line 8 but when I hit run, it loads and then nothing happens, no error is shown, it just does nothing, if it makes any more sense I'm on the swift playgrounds app on iPad. Could it be because of that?

Comment: @KevinBryant feel free to edit your question and add any additional information. iPad playground should behave the same way as shown above

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
func increment(array: [Int]) -> [Int] {

    var result = array

    var lastValue = false

    result = result.reversed().map { value in
        if lastValue { return 0 }
        if value == 0 {
            lastValue = true
            return 1
        }
        return value + 1
    }
    result.reverse()
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to getting a height ramp (which seems to be what you are trying to achieve) is not to think about incrementing an existing array, but creating it. The following code demonstrates this:

```swift
let heightCount = 10
let rampCount = heightCount // can be any value <= heightCount
for ramp in 1...rampCount {
    let rampHeights = [Int](repeating: 0, count: heightCount-ramp) + [Int](1...ramp)
    print(rampHeights)
}
```

The output from this code will be

```swift
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

As you can see the `heightCount` value determines the overall length of the array and within the loop the `ramp` value determines the number of non-zero values in the *ramp*.

**Note:** the loop is just for demonstration purposes. The key line of code is:

```swift
let rampHeights = [Int](repeating: 0, count: heightCount-ramp) +
                  [Int](1...ramp)
```

which you can put wherever you need in your code. You just need to make sure `heightCount` and `ramp` have appropriate values.